# How to login into website using wget method POST with redirect

Tags: linux, web-scraping, wget, login-script, autologin

***What I'm looking for***

I want to scrape a website and have an alert as soon as there are changes.
But I have a little trouble to understand the authentication mechanism set up by this website.
I tried almost all tricks to be able to connect via wget, but none worked.

The website : [offre.astria.com](https://offre.astria.com)

***What I tried***

```
username=XXXXX  
password=XXXXX

wget --save-cookies cookies.txt \
     --keep-session-cookies \
     --post-data 'username=$username&password=$password' \
     --delete-after \
     https://cas.astria.com/cas-ext/login?service=https://offre.astria.com


wget --load-cookies cookies.txt \
     https://offre.astria.com
```

After your comments, I tried this too :

```
username=XXXX   
password=XXXX
code=`wget -qO- https://cas.astria.com/cas-ext/login?service=https://offre.astria.com | cat | grep 'name="lt"' | cut -d"_" -f2`
hidden_code=_$code
wget --save-cookies cookies.txt \
     --keep-session-cookies \
     --post-data 'username=$username&password=$password&lt=$hidden_code&_eventId=submit' \
     --delete-after \
     https://cas.astria.com/cas-ext/login?service=https://offre.astria.com


wget --load-cookies cookies.txt \
     https://offre.astria.com
```

And the error message goes from http 302 to http 500 servlet internal error.
Maybe, because the hidden field change the value between the first attempt and the second ...

***I tried this too***

```
username=XXXX   
password=XXXX
code=`wget -qO- --save-cookies cookies.txt --keep-session-cookies --delete-after https://cas.astria.com/cas-ext/login?service=https://offre.astria.com | cat | grep 'name="lt"' | cut -d"_" -f2,3 | cut -d"\"" -f1`
wget --load-cookies cookies.txt \
     --post-data 'username=$username&password=$password&lt=$hidden_code&_eventId=submit' \
     --delete-after \
     https://cas.astria.com/cas-ext/login?service=https://offre.astria.com


wget --load-cookies cookies.txt \
     https://offre.astria.com
```

And same results :s

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the source of the web page, you will find the login form has a hidden field:

```
<input type="hidden" name="lt" value="_c72D26258-FFFE-C561-D3EC-9BAC7F85B9A4_kCB5ECD54-57E0-1FD5-8A2F-BF72E114C604" />
```

The value of this field is generated server side, and changes every time you refresh the page.

This is a mechanism to prevent exactly what you are trying to do.

You may be able to bypass it, by having a script read the page, extract the value, and then use `wget` to submit a proper form.

It is however possible that you will encounter other defensive methods on the site.

Comment: *"This is a mechanism to prevent exactly what you are trying to do..."* - Selenium and Python to the rescue.

Comment: Thank you much much for the idea, check my edited question ^^

Comment: @jww Seems that you have a clear idea about what my solution should look like ? thank you by advance : )

Comment: Hi there, hope that someone could help me

Comment: anyone to help pleaaase

Comment: @JeanDupont I don't think anyone here can help you further. I checked your code to extract the extra parameter, and it works correctly. Error 500 is internal server error. Whatever you are doing, their server code does not like it. This needs debugging, which needs credentials for the site, and might violate their TOS. One last thing I can suggest to you is: try Wireshark. Capture traffic from your browser when you successfully log in, and see what you are missing.